# how to fix this problem about insert into new table from another table in mysql

Tags: mysql-workbench

so i want to insert the data buyer who do transaction in month 7, 8, 9 in 2017, i try my syntax but it was wrong

INSERT INTO julsept17_total2 (buyer_Id) SELECT b.buyer_id from order_buyer b where month(b.createdAt) in (7, 8, 9) and year(b.createdAt)=2017;

do you know where my wrong at?

Comment: I actually don't see anything wrong with your insert statement.  Can you include the exact error you are getting?

Comment: it was said that my query are interupted

Comment: i think you should replace 2017 with '2017', probably the same for the months but I'm not sure

Comment: @laserany No, that's incorrect advice.  Both the `MONTH` and `YEAR` functions should be returning integers, not text.  But, even so, that shouldn't be causing any error, because MySQL could cope with an implicit conversion.

Comment: Please provide the exact error message you're getting. Not *it was wrong* or *it was said that my query are interrupted*, but the **exact** error message.

Comment: tbh idk where to check the exact error message on mysql workbench

Comment: how many columns are present in the table `julsept17_total2`. if you have multiple columns. please check whether it has a default value for each column present  in the table.

Comment: You're the one that said *it was said that my query are interrupted*. Then you say *idk where to check the exact error message*. Your whole problem statement is *i try my syntax but it was wrong*. You've not told us what was *wrong*, and when we ask you to give us that information you say *idk*. If you can't tell us what *it was wrong* means specifically, and you can't explain any sort of problem in a way that tells us anything, how are we supposed to be able to help?